# Flow of a vector field in order to calculate the Lie derivative

Tags: differential-geometry

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be vector fields on $\mathbb{R}^3$ defined by $$X_p= \frac{\partial}{\partial x} - \frac{y}{2}\frac{\partial}{\partial z} \ \text{ and } \ Y_p = \frac{\partial}{\partial y} + \frac{x}{2}\frac{\partial}{\partial z}.$$ Find the maximal integral curve of $X$ starting at $p_0=(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ and compute the Lie derivative $\mathscr{L}_XY$ directly using the definition $$\mathscr{L}_XY = \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{(\varphi_{-t})_*Y_{\varphi(t,p)} - Y_{p}}{t}.$$

To find the maximal of $X$ starting at $p_0$ curve it suffices to solve the differential equations $$\begin{align*} \frac{dx}{dt} &= 1 \\ \frac{dy}{dt} &= 0 \\ \frac{dz}{dt} &= -\frac{y}{2}.\end{align*}$$

The first one gives $x(t) = t + c_1$, the second gives that $y(t) = c_2$ and the last one that $z(t) = -\frac{y}{2}t + c_3 = - \frac{c_2}{2}t+c_3$. So the maximal integral curve is of the form $$\gamma(t)=(t+c_1, c_2,-\frac{c_2}{2}t+c_3)$$ for $t \in \mathbb{R}$. The inital condition gives that $\gamma(0) = (x_0, y_0, z_0) \implies  c_1=x_0, c_2=y_0, c_3= z_0$.

I'm very confused for the second part of the problem. I don't really understand this flow map $\varphi$. I can see the intuition that $$\varphi : (-\varepsilon, \varepsilon) \times W \to U$$ where $U$ is a neighborhood of $p_0$ gives integral curves of $X$ for every $t \in (-\varepsilon, \varepsilon)$, but I don't see how I can compute this at all?

Comment: If you fix the time parameter $t$, the flow map $\varphi:(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\times \mathbb R^3\rightarrow \mathbb R^3,(t,p)\mapsto\varphi(t,p)=\varphi_{t}(p)$ becomes a map $\psi:\mathbb R^3\rightarrow \mathbb R^3$. So in the end you just have to compute the usual differential of this map and the image of the vector $Y_{\varphi(t,p)}$.

Comment: So I think I have that $$Y_{\varphi(t,p)} = \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \vert_{\varphi(t,p)} + \frac{t + x_0}{2} \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \vert_{\varphi(t,p)}.$$ Now calculating $\varphi_{-t, *}(Y_{\varphi(t,p)})$ gives me headache. I don't really know how to compute this. @T.P.

Comment: Do you know how to compute the Jacobian matrix of the map $\psi(x,y,z):=\varphi_{-t}(x,y,z)$?

Comment: The Jacobian of $\varphi_{-1}(x,y,z) = (-t + x, y, -\frac{y}{2}(-t) + z)$ should be $$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\ 0&1&0\\ 0&\frac{t}{2}&1\end{pmatrix}$$ in this case. @T.P.

Comment: Then apply this matrix to the vector $Y_{\varphi(t,x,y,z)}$ and you have the part that your missing.

Comment: By applying do you mean computing $$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\ \:0&1&0\\ \:0&\frac{t}{2}&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1\\ \:0\\ \:\frac{t+x}{2}\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1\\ 0\\ \frac{t+x}{2}\end{pmatrix}?$$ @T.P.

Comment: Yes the differential is a 3x3-matrix and acts on 3-vectors by left multiplication. That’s what is meant by $(\varphi_{−t})_∗Y_{\varphi(t,p)}$

Comment: BTW you have a mistake in your 3-vector above, $0$ and $1$ must be interchanged.